# How to create fixed array of volatile struct function pointers

Tags: c, struct, arm, volatile, cortex-m

How does one create an array of `volatile` structs?  Each struct contains 3 function pointers.

i.e. is it

```
State_t * volatile states[10];
```

or

```
volatile State_t * states[10];
```

??

Also, should the struct properties be defined as `volatile` as well?

This is to ensure function pointers are not cleared by compiler.  Code works fine when compiled with `GCC`. However, the second entry in the array returns rubbish compiled with the ARM compiler for Cortex-M3.

Comment: `State_t * volatile states[10]` volatile pointers; `volatile State_t * states[10]` volatile contents; `volatile State_t * volatile states[10]` volatile pointers and contents.

Comment: Additionally, the latter two statements declare the complete contents of the struct volatile. If you only want to have individual members declared as such, you should do that in the struct definition

Comment: I think you need to clarify that you are asking about a difference between gcc and the ARM compiler, not general information about declaring volatile structs or pointers.

Comment: sorry.. Still starting out on embedded C >.<

Answer (score 1):

```
State_t *volatile states[10];
```

The above means `states` is an array of `10` volatile pointers to objects of type `State_t`. The `volatile` keyword here qualifies the pointers, not the value pointed to.

```
State_t volatile *states[10];
```

The above means `states` is an array of `10` pointers to objects of type `volatile State_t`. Here, the `volatile` keyword qualifies not the the pointer, but the value pointed to. The above can also be written as

```
volatile State_t *states[10];
```

To answer the latter part of your question, if you qualify a structure variable as `volatile`, then all its members are `volatile`. However, the `volatile` qualification is not part of the structure definition.

```
volatile struct states {
    // stuff

} state_a;

struct states state_b;
```

Here, `state_a` is `volatile` qualified but `state_b` is not. Therefore, you need to qualify each `states` instance explicitly as `volatile` unless you create `states` instances in the same statement as the structure definition.

Comment: Thank you!!  Managed to solve it by rewriting the manager.  Apparently it might have been a struct misalignment (hence the corrupted values).